# Android detect URL video in Webview

Tags: java, android, webview

In my Android app, I have a custom Webview. How do I detect the video URL in the webview?

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(addressBar));

buttonGo.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        goUrl();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()); 

String currentUrl; 

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override 
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {         
            currentUrl=url;
            return true; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: thank you support, but how to detect a video is being played in WebView?